# How to delete element from list in c++

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

I am currently making a singly linked list in C++
Now I'm trying to make a function `showList` that prints the content of the list and if it is empty, prints "Empty list". However, right now it prints the list **and** "Empty list" every single time. When the list is empty, it prints an empty line and in new line "Empty list"
Here is my current code:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T data;
    Node* next;
};

template <typename T>
void showList(const Node<T>* head){
    
    while (head != nullptr){
        std::cout << head->data << " " ;
        head = head->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if(head->data = 0){
       std::cout << "Empty list"<< std::endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Pop quiz: when the `while` loop ends: 1) what is the value of `head`, 2) given #1, what would be the value of `head->data`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The value of head would be the same? I assume it doesnt change anything. head->data would be nullptr

Comment: What do you mean "the same"? What value do you believe that `head` must be, in order for the `while` loop to terminate? And, given `head` being that value, what do you think `head->data` will mean? And since `data` is not a pointer, how do you expect it to become `nullptr`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It must be nullptr. And now I realize that the head, not data must be nullptr. It doesn't make sense. I just tried everything I found and this was one of the proposed solutions, but it didn't work.

Comment: `if(head->data = 0)` should raise a warning on most compilers. Did you really meant to assign zero to the `data` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean an empty list is a list where `head` is `nullptr`, you could check it explicitly:

```
void showList(const Node<T>* head) {
    if (head == nullptr) {
       std::cout << "Empty list"<< std::endl;
       return;
    }
    
    while (head != nullptr){
        std::cout << head->data << " " ;
        head = head->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: In this case, the `while` loop can be changed into a `do..while` loop so the `head` check is not done twice redundantly on the 1st iteration: `do { ... } while (head != nullptr);` Upon entering the loop, `head` is already guaranteed to not be `nullptr` on the 1st iteration so there is no need to validate that again.